# Does the short-rest bonus from the chef feat from TCoE stack with the the short-rest bonus of cook's utensils in XGtE

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, stacking

The chef feat grants, among other benefits, the ability to cook a meal during a short rest

> As part of a short rest, you can cook special food,
> provided you have ingredients and cook's utensils
> on hand. You can prepare enough of this food for a
> number of creatures equal to 4 + your proficiency
> bonus. At the end of the short rest, any creature
> who eats the food and spends one or more Hit
> Dice to regain hit points regains an extra 1d8
> hit points. [1]

Cook's utensils themselves already grant a bonus when used to cook a meal during a short rest

> As part of a short rest, you can prepare a tasty meal that helps your companions regain their strength. You and up to five creatures of your choice regain 1 extra hit point per Hit Die spent during a short rest, provided you have access to your cook’s utensils and sufficient food. [2]

Do these benefits stack so that you can give in total 1d8+`number of Hit Dice spent` to yourself and up to five creatures who use hit dice?

---

[1] Tasha's Cauldron of Everything, page 79 
[2] Xanathar's Guide to Everything, page 81

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Probably

The two effects do not have the same name, which would prevent them from stacking. So that is no problem.

It's open to interpretation whether the "special food" required by the chef feat is also "tasty food" as required by the utensils, I could not find any RAW information on that. But as both foods give extra hp, they seem to be similar enough. So this probably works.

However do note that everything in both books is **optional**. So your DM is free to not allow the extra effect from Xanathars guide.